# How to display nested JSON objects using ng-repeat with Ionic framework?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I am developing a simple hybrid mobile app using the Ionic framework. When you search for a last name, a GET request is sent to retrieve all matching last names, and then displays their corresponding ID's. I am having an issue displaying the returned data from the JSON object.

Below is the html page:

```
<ion-view view-title="Account" ng-controller="AccountCtrl">
<ion-content>
    <div class="list">
        <div class="item item-input-inset">
            <label class="item-input-wrapper">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="name">
            </label>
            <button class="button button-small" ng-click="searchUser(name)">
                Go
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul ng-repeat="user in $results">
            <li>{{user.id}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Next is the js file that successfully returns a populated JSON object with everything I need.

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AccountCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.searchUser = function (name) {
    $http.get('https://notrelevantforthis/searchLastName?=' + name).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)

        //Assign JSON obj to results to repeat through and display data
        $scope.results = response.data;

        //To show the actual JSON object is returned
        //var jsonStr = JSON.stringify($scope.results);
        //document.body.innerHTML = jsonStr;

    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error)
    });
};
}]);
```

Now the important part is the structure of the JSON object itself. I think this is where I am getting confused. The structure is like the following:

```
{
"response": {
  "totalFound": 275,
  "start": 0,
  "acc": [
    {
      "id": [
        "1"
      ],
      "first_name": [
        "Joe"
      ],
      "last_name": [
        "Smith"
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": [
        "2"
      ],
      "first_name": [
        "John"
      ],
      "last_name": [
        "Doe"
      ]
   }]}
}
```

My problem is iterating through the JSON object using ng-repeat I think. For some reason none of the data is being displayed, but the object is definitely there when looking at the console. Any help or direction in what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated, as I am new to this and have been trying to find the correct way to do this.

**EDIT:** 
Tried using collection-repeat as well offered by the ionic framework but was getting stack limit errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're assigning `response.data` to `$scope.results`, you're literally assigning the HTTP's response body to it, which is the whole JSON object that you have in your question. You would need to actually point to `response.data.response.acc` if you wanted to `ng-repeat` through those accounts.

In your template, it should just be `ng-repeat="user in results"`, without the `$` in front of `results`.

Your JSON object lists the `id` for each account as an array, I'd recommend just giving the literal value without the array, otherwise in your ng-repeat you'll have to use `{{user.id[0]}}` to actual print the value without printing the array itself.

I've created an example for you here: http://plnkr.co/edit/GYeF4FzVHl8Og5QTFcDx?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @Dennis, going to take a hard look at this again soon and will let you know my results.

Comment: Just checked and you were right. I was definitely pointing to the wrong information that I needed! I revised the scope variable to point to what I need, as you suggested. Thanks for the great answer for what I was trying to do @Dennis Tang